# values not equal in sqlite and json array in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am trying to compare the value in sqlite table and id of the webservice what i have done so far is

```
      if(data_exist!=bookProduct.length()){
               Log.i("in update","m here");
               Cursor cursors = getRawEvents("select id from bcuk_book");
               try{  
                       for (int i = 0; i < bookProduct.length(); i++) 
                       {
                       JSONObject c = bookProduct.getJSONObject(i);
                       String Bid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                       ArrayList<String> mapId = new ArrayList<String>();
                       while(cursors.moveToNext())
                       {
                           Log.e("cursors",cursors.getString(0));
                                 Log.i(Bid,Bid);
                                 if(cursors.getString(0)!=c.getString(TAG_ID)){
                                     Log.e("fas",Bid);
                                 }
                                 }
                                mapId.add(TAG_ID);
                                 Log.e(Bid,Bid);
                             }

                     }
```

My issue is i am getting same values in logs..

```
          if(cursors.getString(0)!=c.getString(TAG_ID)){
```

this condition says if they are not equal then print the log..But the issue is i am entering into that block even i am getting same values from sqlite and TAG_ID i.e from json webservice..How to solve this.Where i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(!cursors.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(TAG_ID)))
```

This is String is not return null value but return " " between them